# Find EmailTemplate Used in EmailMessage

Tags: soql, emailmessage

Is there a way to find out if/what emailTemplate was used on an outbound EmailMessage?

Looking in Eclipse I cannot see any relationship between the two (or in the schema builder tool), nor a field on the EmailMessage that could correspond to the EmailTemplate.

Comment: [Doesn't look like it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Medium: Yes but you will have to parse through the EmailMessage looking for text that will uniquely identify a template.

Long answer: Yes with a couple of conditions. You can't have the exact template twice with the only changes being in the merge fields UNLESS you can distinguish between the objects. You'd need to call a method that would parse the text looking for the unique template identifiers (you'll probably want methods to for each template). It's certainly possible but not the greatest. I can't recommend more without knowing your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this link http://www.adminhero.com/workbench-admins-best-friend/ that shows a way to see the reverse - how many times a template has been used.

Perhaps this may help you with what you are looking for.